# WSO2 identity server - forgot / reset / email password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 identity server support functionality that allows users to reset or send password reminder emails?

I couldn't see anything about this functionality in the online documentation, or by playing with the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to do a small correction to my previous answer. Currently this feature is not in the product by default, you need to add it via feature manager.

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: You need to install Admin-mgt feature from the p2 repository. Snapshot p2 repository can be found from [1] http://wso2.org/bamboo/artifact/WSO2CARBON-P2REPO/JOB1/build-143/P2-Repo/p2-repo Please follow the steps given here, to install features from the p2 repo [2] http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-install-bpel-features-via.html You can install features using Carbon Management Console or via Equinox OSGi console. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is already available with WSO2 products.
You can check this with WSO2 Identity Server snapshot build [1].
This [2] is written for wso2 stratos, but the idea is similar in carbon products.

[1] http://wso2.org/bamboo/browse/WSO2CARBON-PRODUCTS-266/artifact/JOB1/IS

[2] https://stratoslive.wso2.com/carbon/admin-mgt/docs/userguide.html

[3] fyi: http://old.nabble.com/The-forgot-password-functionality-is-included-into-the-products-td33184156.html

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Thilini